# Link to a text file

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, how do we make a link to a text file? The file is not managed by Drupal, but hosted within the same domain.

For example, I'm building a Drupal 8 module and on its help page I'd like to link to its `README.txt` file. I thought this would work:

```
$readmePath = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/README.txt';
$readmeLink = \Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl(
  t('README'),
  \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri($readmePath)
)->toString();
```

This unfortunately does not work, and instead throws a 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API documentation for [Url::fromUri()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8) states the following regarding the $uri parameter:

> string $uri: The URI of the resource including the scheme. For user
>   input that may correspond to a Drupal route, use internal: for the
>   scheme. For paths that are known not to be handled by the Drupal
>   routing system (such as static files), use base: for the scheme to get
>   a link relative to the Drupal base path (like the  HTML
>   element). For a link to an entity you may use
>   entity:{entity_type}/{entity_id} URIs.

So I think that you would need to do,

```
$readmePath = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/README.txt';
$readmeLink = \Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl(
  t('README'),
  \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('base:' . $readmePath)
)->toString();
```